# D3 bar graph looking different when using numbers array and json elements array

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I want both of those D3 graphs start from the bottom. But, for some reason, the second one is shown starting from the top

[Graph1](https://plnkr.co/edit/6QntNz3d8m6CJJFBQgiQ) - Just showing the JS code

```
var datos = [1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 11, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144];

function graficar() {
    d3.select('.miGrafica')
        .selectAll('div')
        .data(datos)
        .enter().append('div')
        .attr('class', 'barra')
        .style("height", function(d) {
            return d + "px";
        })
        .text(function(d) {
            return d.nombre;
        })
}
```

[image: Graph looking ok]

[Graph2](https://plnkr.co/edit/rUxDv3VxSPyB3Zu887xm) - Just showing the JS code

```
var datos = [{id:1,nombre:"Fregona",cantidad:45},{id:2,nombre:"Escoba",cantidad:26}];


function graficar() {
    d3.select(".miGrafica")
        .selectAll("div")
        .data(datos)
        .enter().append("div")
        .attr("id",function(d) {
            return d.id;
        })
        .attr('class', 'barra')
        .style("height", function(d) {
            return d.cantidad + "px";
        })
        .text(function(d) {
            return d.nombre;
        });
}
```

[image: Graph starting from the top]

HTML in both cases is the same

```
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Dibujando con datos</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
    <script data-require="d3@3.5.3" data-semver="3.5.3" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body onload="graficar()">
    <div class="miGrafica"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

And CSS

```
.barra {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-right: 2px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm a newbie with D3.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How did you set up the range - d3.scale.linear().range(...)?

Comment: Didn't set it. Is it needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one difference between two examples - text in bars.
So, you need to add css rules for text aligning or remove `text` in bars:

Bars without text: https://plnkr.co/edit/1DG3yCfCNdLAiNp0u6fK

Bars with text and with css rule `vertical-align: bottom;` https://plnkr.co/edit/TWksL0fVUAubdHaYsvty

Comment: And there is no problems with d3, it's just html and css.